# background-image and position relative white border

Tags: html, css

When I place a div with a background-image property and use position: relative I end up with a white frame around the edge of the image which I do not want.

I cannot use absolute as I need an element to follow directly below the background image and scale on different resolutions (so no setting height/width in px).

Here's the CSS:

```
#pagehead{
    position: relative;
    background-position: center, center;
    background-image: url("Header.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

section{
    position: relative;
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="animate.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="page.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="pagehead"></div>

    <section>
        <div id="content">
            blahblahblah
        </div>
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting 'body { margin: 0px }'?

Comment: Can't believe it was that simple! Thank you that worked :) If you post as an answer I will mark answered.

Comment: Will do! Sometimes, it's the small things that matter :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the body's margin to 0 might fix the problem:

```
body { margin: 0px; }
```